# Python Multiprocessing Too Many Files Open

Tags: python, ubuntu, multiprocessing

I'm using Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu, trying to run a function over rows of a pandas dataframe - the function takes the data in the row and uses it to create many more (84 to be exact) rows for a new dataframe. The input dataframe has over 15M rows, so this is a slow process to run serially. To process in parallel, I'm using the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, Queue

def expandDates(row):
    expd = do stuff
    return resExpand.put(expd)

resExpand, results = Queue(), []

procs = []
for row in thisData.itertuples():
    p = Process(target=expandDates, args=[row])
    p.start()
    procs.append(p)
for proc in procs:
    results.append(resExpand.get())
    proc.join()
    proc.close()
```

This was giving me an OS Error - Too Many Files Open, so I thought I would process the dataframe in chunks, giving me this:

```
chunkSize = 500
chunks = math.ceil(len(thisData)/chunkSize)
chunkIndices = list(range(0, chunks*chunkSize, chunkSize))
for (indx, (fm, to)) in enumerate(zip(chunkIndices, chunkIndices[1:])):
    # get the chunk
    thisChunk = thisData.iloc[fm:to]
    # process
    procs = []
    for row in thisChunk.itertuples():
        p = Process(target=expandDates, args=[row])
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
    for proc in procs:
        results.append(resExpand.get())
        proc.join()
        proc.close()
```

As I understand, this should limit the multiprocessing to 500 rows at a time, which should be well under the limit of the number of files that can be opened. What am I missing? I'm not sure how I can even debug this. Thanks.

Comment: You could just increase your OS's file limit (google for e.g. `ubuntu increase file limit`).

Comment: I guess that each subprocess additionally needs sockets or pipes to communicate with the main process so you would have a multiple of 30_000 open file(-like)s.

Comment: Better use a `multiprocessing.Pool` or a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have a better time with `multiprocessing.Pool`; select a number of parallel workers (or don't, to have Python look at the number of CPU cores you have), and submit your work, then deal with the results:

```
import multiprocessing


def expandDates(row):
    return row, do_stuff(row)


def main():
    with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:
        for row, result in pool.imap(expandDates, this_data.itertuples()):
            print(row, result)
```

Comment: This fails:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 868, in next
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'pandas.core.frame.Pandas'>: attribute lookup Pandas on pandas.core.frame failed

Comment: @Dr.Andrew Ah, right – you'll need `iterrows()` (or something that doesn't try to create namedtuples).

Comment: Thanks @AKX - I realized that and switched to itertuples(name=None), so that part seems ok. Testing the multiprocessing now.